# Azure Network Watcher - connection monitor vs connection troubleshoot

Tags: azure, connection, cloud, devops, monitoring

Can someone please explain me that what is difference between Azure Network Watcher - connection monitor and connection *troubleshoot*? ( I have not done them practically, just gone through about those then got this doubt )
Thanks in Advance.